# regex- Extracting in different strings

Tags: java, regex

I have this String :

```
Date Description Amount Price Charge Shares Owned
04/30/13 INCOME REINVEST 0.0245 $24.66 $12.34 1.998 1,008.369
05/31/13 INCOME REINVEST 0.0228 $22.99 $12.22 1.881 1,010.250
06/28/13 INCOME REINVEST 0.0224 $22.63 $11.97 1.891 1,012.141
```

I want to extract The dates in a string say "matchedDate" similarly description which in this case are "INCOME REINVEST", "INCOME REINVEST" "INCOME REINVEST"

Amount in a array which happen to be : "0.0245","0.0228","0.0224"

Price in a array :"24.66", "22.99", "22.63"

Charge in a array :"12.34","12.22","11.97"

Shares in a array :"1.998","1.881","1.891"

I don't need the last part "Owned" that corresponds to 1,008.369,1,010.250 and 1,012.141

So far I am able to successfully extract dates by this:

```
String regex="[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}";
Pattern dateMatch = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = dateMatch.matcher(regString);
while (m.find()) {
String[] matchedDate=new String[] {m.group()};
for(int count=0;count<matchedDate.length;count++){
sysout(matchedDate[count]
}
```

regString being the string i am trying to do a match on i.e the table i explained in the first block.

I don't need the $ sign's so we can store the numbers in integer arrays. I think we have to identify some kind of pattern of spaces and dollar to do this.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I tried to include as much of an explanation as I could.  Hopefully it helps.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
String regString = "04/30/13 INCOME REINVEST 0.0245 $24.66 $12.34 1.998 1,008.36";
String regex="([0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2})\\s*([\\w ]+)\\s*(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)\\s*\\$(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)\\s*\\$(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)\\s*(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)\\s*(\\d+(,\\d{3})*(\\.\\d+)?)";
Pattern match = Pattern.compile(regex);

Matcher m = match.matcher(regString);
while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1)); //04/30/13
        System.out.println(m.group(2)); //INCOME REINVEST
        System.out.println(m.group(3)); //0.0245
        System.out.println(m.group(5)); //24.66
        System.out.println(m.group(7)); //12.34
        System.out.println(m.group(9)); //1.998
        System.out.println(m.group(11)); //1,008.86
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/Pp5A23)

**Regex Breakdown:**

`([0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2})` - Your date regex.

`([\\w ]+)` - Description - 1+ Word characters and spaces.

`(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)` (used 4 times) - Amount, Price, Charge, Shares - 1+ number potentially followed by a `.` and at least 1 more number.

`(\\d+(,\\d{3})*(\\.\\d+)?)` - 1+ number, followed potentially by sequences of a `,` and 3 numbers, followed potentially by a `.` and at least 1 more number.

Comment: no i am not kind of comfortable at regex. Don't much about groups . so It would be very nice of you if you could ellaborate

Comment: updated showing you where each of the values is found. Now you can put each of those m.group(x) values in its relevant array.

Answer (score 0):

```
String r = "([0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}).+?\\$((?:(?:\\d+|\\d+,\\d+)\\.\\d+\\s\\$?){3})";
String list = "04/30/13 INCOME REINVEST 0.0245 $24.66 $12.34 1.998 1,008.369"; 

Matcher m = Pattern.compile(r).matcher(list);

while (m.find()) 
{
    String myData = m.group(1) + " " + m.group(2).replace("$", "");
    String[] data = myData.split(" ");

    for(String s : data)
        System.out.println(s);
}
```

Outputs:

> 04/30/13
>   24.66
>   12.34
>   1.998

`.+?\\$`: non-greedy to ensure that we don't take a `'$'`--basically skips everything until `'$'`
`((?:(?:\\d+|\\d+,\\d+)\\.\\d+\\s\\$?){3}` uses a capturing group to get the three numbers of interest, but with one of the `'$'`, which is removed via `.replace()`  You could do this with `.replace()`, but the expression would be fairly long.
`(?:\\d+|\\d+,\\d+)` says "group, but do not capture" a number or #,#
`\\.\\d+\\s\\$?` says a `'.'` followed by a #, followed by whitespace and an optional `'$'`

Here's a general tutorial on [Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html).  Here's the section on [capturing groups](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html).
 Good luck!

Comment: this looks good, but this doesn't prints out my date..why.? neither it would print description. 

04/30/13 INCOME REINVEST 24.66 12.34 1.998

How would i get this all I seperated by a space so that i can further process the array . Thank you :)

Comment: @rahul888 Sorry, didn't realize that you wanted the date printed out, too. Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

This should match the parts you need:

```
(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}).+?([\d.]+)\s\$(\S+)\s\$(\S+)\s(\S+)
```

Explained:

```
(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}) - capture date
.+? - match anything up to next number
([\d.]+)\s - capture Amount but match space following it
$(\S+)\s - capture Price but match space following it
$(\S+)\s - capture Charge but match space following it
(\S+) - capture Shares
```

Comment: This doesn't work with commas, and also captures junk in the various numbers, instead of actual prices.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you need and it will also run for any number of similar records on your input string ...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {

private static Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("([0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2})\\s+([a-zA-Z]+\\s[a-zA-Z]+)\\s+(\\d{1}\\.\\d{0,4})\\s+\\$(\\d{1,2}\\.\\d{0,2})\\s+\\$(\\d{1,2}\\.\\d{0,2})\\s+(\\d{1,2}\\.\\d{0,3})\\s+");

public static void main(String a[] ) {      

  String regString = "04/30/13 INCOME REINVEST 0.0245 $24.66 $12.34 1.998 1,008.369 " +
        "05/31/13 INCOME REINVEST 0.0228 $22.99 $12.22 1.881 1,010.250 " +
        "06/28/13 INCOME REINVEST 0.0224 $22.63 $11.97 1.891 1,012.141 ";

  ArrayList<String> date = new ArrayList<String>();
  ArrayList<String> desc = new ArrayList<String>();
  ArrayList<String> amt = new ArrayList<String>();
  ArrayList<String> price = new ArrayList<String>();
  ArrayList<String> charge = new ArrayList<String>();
  ArrayList<String> share = new ArrayList<String>();

  Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(regString);     
  while(m.find()) {
      date.add(m.group(1));
      desc.add(m.group(2));
      amt.add(m.group(3));
      price.add(m.group(4));
      charge.add(m.group(5));
      share.add(m.group(6));    
  }

  System.out.println("DATE : " + date.toString());
  System.out.println("DESC : " + desc.toString());
  System.out.println("AMOUNT : " + amt.toString());
  System.out.println("PRICE : " + price.toString());
  System.out.println("CHARGE : " + charge.toString());
  System.out.println("SHARES : " + share.toString());    
}
}
```

The output of the above program is as below,

```
DATE : [04/30/13, 05/31/13, 06/28/13]
DESC : [INCOME REINVEST, INCOME REINVEST, INCOME REINVEST]
AMOUNT : [0.0245, 0.0228, 0.0224]
PRICE : [24.66, 22.99, 22.63]
CHARGE : [12.34, 12.22, 11.97]
SHARES : [1.998, 1.881, 1.891]
```